# Carregar os dados na tabela de um div dentro de um form

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

**Tenho este formulário:**

```html
<form name="form4" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >
 
 <h1><center><strong>Saída de Luvas</strong></center></h1></br>
 
    <p><h5><strong>Data de Saída</strong></h5> <input id="DataSaida" type="date" name="DataSaida" required="" ></p></br>

    <label for=""><h5><strong>Funcionario</strong></h5></label>
    <select id="first_dd" name="Funcionario">
 
   <option value="0">Selecione Produto</option>

      <option value="1">Alice</option>

      <option value="2">Ana Ferreira</option>

      <option value="3">Ana Paula</option>
   
   <option value="4">Anabela</option>

      <option value="5">Bernardete Moreira</option>
   
   <option value="6">Clarinda Fernandes</option>

      <option value="7">Conceição</option>
   
   <option value="8">Enfermagem</option>

      <option value="9">Eunice</option>

      <option value="10">Fátima Belchior</option>
   
   <option value="11">Fernanda Pereira</option>

      <option value="12">Fisioterapia</option>

      <option value="13">Florinda</option>
   
   <option value="14">Georgina</option>

      <option value="15">Helena Ferreirinha</option>

      <option value="16">Isabel Barge</option>
   
   <option value="17">Isabel Gomes</option>

      <option value="18">Joana Lopes</option>

      <option value="19">Joaquim Cunha</option>

      <option value="20">Luísa Almeida</option>

      <option value="21">Manuela Moreno </option>
   
   <option value="22">Maria José Pereira</option>

      <option value="23">Maria Mendes</option>

      <option value="24">Mário Ferreira</option>
   
   <option value="25">Mário Oliveira</option>

      <option value="26">Marisa Silva</option>

      <option value="27">Mónica</option>
   
   <option value="28">Mónica Susana</option>

      <option value="29">Patricia Inácio</option>

      <option value="30">Paula Barbosa</option>
   
   <option value="31">Paula Rodrigues</option>

      <option value="32">Paula Silva</option>

      <option value="33">Silvia Borges</option>
   
   <option value="34">WC Refeitório</option>
   
    </select>
 </br>
 </br>

     <p><h5><strong>Função</strong></h5> <div id="Funcao" name="Funcao"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="terceiro_dd_div"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Tamanho</strong></h5> <div id="quarto_dd_div"></div></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Quantidade</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" required="" size="40" /><br/></p></br>
  
  <p><h5><strong>Observações</strong></h5></br>
<textarea type="text" id="Observacoes" name="Observacoes" rows="2" cols="90"></textarea><br/></p></br>
  
 <input type="submit" value="Registar"/>
</form>

    <script>

      var first_dd = document.getElementById('first_dd');
      var Funcao = document.getElementById('Funcao');
      var food = [[''], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Enfermagem'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Fisioterapia'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Pedologista'], ['AAD'], ['Estágio'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['AAD'], ['Outro']];
      var terceiro_dd_div = document.getElementById('terceiro_dd_div');
      var food1 = [[''], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Nitrilo'], ['Vinil s/ pó'], ['Nitrilo']];
      var quarto_dd_div = document.getElementById('quarto_dd_div');
      var food2 = [[''], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['L'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L'], ['M'], ['S'], ['M'], ['M'], ['M'], ['L']];

   first_dd.onchange = getFood;
   

      function getFood() {

        var val = this.value;

        var html_str = '<select>';

        for (var i = 0, len = food[val].length; i < len; i++) {

          html_str += '<option>' + food[val][i]  + '</option>';
    html_str += '<option>' + food1[val][i]  + '</option>';
    html_str += '<option>' + food2[val][i]  + '</option>';

        }

        html_str += '</select>';

        Funcao.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  terceiro_dd_div.innerHTML = html_str;
  
  quarto_dd_div.innerHTML = html_str;

      }
  

    </script>
```

Os valores dos campos função, tipo de luvas e tamanho não são carregados na variável nem na tabela, mas preciso desses valores nas variáveis para fazer o update na tabela de stock, porque preciso dessas variáveis no where do update. 
**O código que tenho é este:**

```
<?php  
$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$data = $_POST['DataSaida'];
$funcionario = $_POST['Funcionario'];
$funcao = $_POST['Funcao']; 
$tipoluva = $_POST['TipoLuva'];
$tamanho = $_POST['Tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade'];
$observacoes = $_POST['Observacoes'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO RegSaidaLuvas (`DataSaida`,`Funcionario`,`Funcao`,`TipoLuva`,`Tamanho`,`Quantidade`,`Observacoes`) `VALUES ('$data','$funcionario','$funcao','$tipoluva','$tamanho','$quantidade','$observacoes')";`

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

 $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

**Preciso de fazer este update na tabela do stock:**

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE StockLuvas SET Quantidade = Quantidade -" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockLuvas.IdTipoLuvas =" . $tipoluva AND "StockLuvas.IdTamanho =" . $tamanho;
```

Comment: Não está funcionando pois você está criando os `select` sem o atributo `name`.

Comment: Quando diz `Select`, refere-se a esta parte do código `<p><h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="terceiro_dd_div"></div></p></br>`? Já acrescentei o name do campo da tabela e a variável fica sem o valor do preenchimento do formulário

Comment: Quando você define o `select` dessa forma `var html_str = '<select>';`, você de atribuir um "nome" para ele: `var html_str = '<select name="Funcao">';`. Somente dessa forma o `PHP` irá reconhecer o campo e você poderá atualizar o banco de dados. Os `select` deve ter nomes diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado......Resolvido..

Comment: Eu quero criar dois `Select` como este `var html_str = '<select name="Funcao">';` para inserir na tabela e atribuir valor à variável, mas quero que o `<p><h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5> <div id="terceiro_dd_div"></div></p></br>` fique invisível no formulário para o utilizador.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa usar `js` para armazenar vários valores iguais e depois criar o `select`. Você pode simplesmente criar um `select` e deixa-lo oculto.

Segue um exemplo de como fazer:

```js
// Captura o "select" com a lista de funcionários
var listaFuncionarios = document.querySelector("select[name=\"Funcionario\"]");

// Captura a "div" com as listas de funções, tamanhos e tipos de luva
var listaFuncoes = document.querySelector("#lista-funcoes");
var listaTamanhos = document.querySelector("#lista-tamanhos");
var listaTipoLuvas = document.querySelector("#lista-tipo-luvas");

/* Só irá funcionar para os 6 primeiros, afinal é apenas um exemplo. */
var funcoesPorFuncionarios = ["AAD","Enfermagem","Enfermagem","Pedologista","Outro","Estágio"];
var tamanhoPorFuncionarios = ["L","L","L","M","M","L"];
var tipoLuvaPorFuncionarios = ["Nitrilo","Nitrilo","Vinil s/ pó","Vinil s/ pó","Nitrilo","Nitrilo"];

// Adiciona um evento no "select" da lista de funcionários. Quando o "select" sofrer alterações no valor, o evento será disparado.
listaFuncionarios.addEventListener("change", function() {

  /* Remove a classe "display", responsável por exibir os campos */
  listaFuncoes.classList.remove("display");
  listaTamanhos.classList.remove("display");
  listaTipoLuvas.classList.remove("display");

  if (this.value > 0) {
    /* Adiciona a classe "display", responsável por exibir os campos */
    listaFuncoes.classList.add("display");
    listaTamanhos.classList.add("display");
    listaTipoLuvas.classList.add("display");
    
    /* Preenche os "select" de forma automática */
    listaFuncoes.querySelector("select").value = funcoesPorFuncionarios[this.value];
    listaTamanhos.querySelector("select").value = tamanhoPorFuncionarios[this.value];
    listaTipoLuvas.querySelector("select").value = tipoLuvaPorFuncionarios[this.value];
  }
});
```

```css
#lista-funcoes,
#lista-tamanhos,
#lista-tipo-luvas {
  display: none
}

.display {
  display: block !important;
  animation: fadein 2s
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form4" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()">
  <h1>
    <center><strong>Saída de Luvas</strong></center>
  </h1>
  <br />

  <h5><strong>Data de Saída</strong></h5>
  <input id="DataSaida" type="date" name="DataSaida" required="">
  <br />

  <label for="">
  <h5><strong>Funcionario</strong></h5>
 </label>

  <select id="first_dd" name="Funcionario">
  <option value="0">Selecione o funcionário</option>
  <option value="1">Alice</option>
  <option value="2">Ana Ferreira</option>
  <option value="3">Ana Paula</option>
  <option value="4">Anabela</option>
  <option value="5">Bernardete Moreira</option>
  <option value="6">Clarinda Fernandes</option>
  <option value="7">Conceição</option>
  <option value="8">Enfermagem</option>
  <option value="9">Eunice</option>
  <option value="10">Fátima Belchior</option>
  <option value="11">Fernanda Pereira</option>
  <option value="12">Fisioterapia</option>
  <option value="13">Florinda</option>
  <option value="14">Georgina</option>
  <option value="15">Helena Ferreirinha</option>
  <option value="16">Isabel Barge</option>
  <option value="17">Isabel Gomes</option>
  <option value="18">Joana Lopes</option>
  <option value="19">Joaquim Cunha</option>
  <option value="20">Luísa Almeida</option>
  <option value="21">Manuela Moreno </option>
  <option value="22">Maria José Pereira</option>
  <option value="23">Maria Mendes</option>
  <option value="24">Mário Ferreira</option>
  <option value="25">Mário Oliveira</option>
  <option value="26">Marisa Silva</option>
  <option value="27">Mónica</option>
  <option value="28">Mónica Susana</option>
  <option value="29">Patricia Inácio</option>
  <option value="30">Paula Barbosa</option>
  <option value="31">Paula Rodrigues</option>
  <option value="32">Paula Silva</option>
  <option value="33">Silvia Borges</option>
  <option value="34">WC Refeitório</option>
 </select>

  <div id="lista-funcoes">
    <h5><strong>Função</strong></h5>
    <select name="Funcao">
      <option value="AAD">AAD</option>
      <option value="Enfermagem">Enfermagem</option>
      <option value="Estágio">Estágio</option>
      <option value="Fisioterapia">Fisioterapia</option>
      <option value="Pedologista">Pedologista</option>
      <option value="Outro">Outro</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="lista-tipo-luvas">
    <h5><strong>Tipo de Luvas</strong></h5>
    <select name="TipoLuva">
      <option value="Vinil s/ pó">Vinil s/ pó</option>
      <option value="Nitrilo">Nitrilo</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="lista-tamanhos">
    <h5><strong>Tamanho</strong></h5>
    <select name="Tamanho">
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h5><strong>Quantidade</strong></h5>
  <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" required="" size="40" /><br/>

  <h5><strong>Observações</strong></h5>
  <br/>
  <textarea type="text" id="Observacoes" name="Observacoes" rows="2" cols="90"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Registar" />
</form>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu da forma que tenho criado com `js` ao selecionar o funcionário, atribui logo a função correta, o tipo de luvas que ele usa e o tamanho e no exemplo que apresentaste isso não acontece, mas é possível?,

Comment: Criei uma pergunta nova para explicar melhor o que preciso com o título:  Esconder dois div do formulário em php

Comment: @Desc alterei minha resposta, verifica se é isso mesmo. Adicionei as variáveis `funcoesPorFuncionarios`, `tamanhoPorFuncionarios` e `tipoLuvaPorFuncionarios` seguindo a ordem do `select Funcionario`

Comment: O meu problema é que desta forma, não consigo fazer o `update` na tabela do stockluvas, uma vez que não tenho as variáveis do `$idTipoLuvas` nem `$IdTamanho` para filtrar no `WHERE`do `UPDATE`. Por exemplo imagina agora desses 4  `SELECT` ele guardar na mesma a variável e fazer o`INSERT` da mesma na tabela, mas o utilizador não o ver, por exemplo o `SELECT` do Tipo de Luvas ficar oculto e não aparecer no formulário. É isso que preciso